# LinkedIn like button

Tags: javascript, php, linkedin-api

Is it possible to add a linkedIn "like post" button on my web page ? Share / follow buttons can be done by LinkedIn plugins but I can't find a way to add the like button.

Thanks

Comment: Why you need Linkedin Like button on your site...

Comment: I have a likes counter under my post and I would like to make it clickable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Linkedin "Like" button equivalent to the Facebook you can insert into your website. It is only for Linkedin network itself. Check [official plugins](https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins).

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation